React Native Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)

 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 10s
I got this problem while running my React native CLI project

This Error is due to missing line in your android/gradle.properties
Steps
Go to your android/gradle.properties and check for this line
 **1.(android.useAndroidX=true)**
 **2.(android.enableJetifier=true)**

if one of these lines are missing just add those to your android/gradle.properties
And it should resolve the problem.
